# Change the return type depending on the parameter value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```ts
function doThing(shouldReturnObject: boolean): string | object {
    return shouldReturnObject ? { hello: 'world' } : 'hello world';
}
```

I want the return value to be an object when `shouldReturnObject` equals true, but a string, when it is false.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is by overloading the function. Overload the function for each parameter value and update the return type like this:

```ts
doThing(shouldReturnObject: true):  object
doThing(shouldReturnObject: false): string
doThing(shouldReturnObject: boolean): string | object {
  return shouldReturnObject ? { hello: 'world' } : 'hello world';
}
```

This can also be achieved, if the parameter is an object. For example:

```ts
interface DoThingsSettings {
  lazyLoading: boolean;
}

doThing(settings: { lazyLoading: false} &  DoThingsSettings): object[]
doThing(settings: { lazyLoading: true} &  DoThingsSettings): string[]
doThing(settings: DoThingsSettings):  object[] |  string[] {
  return settings.lazyLoading ? [{ name: 'Peter' }] : ['/user/1'];
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate in many cases. One thing you didn't mention is it's important to realize that the `shouldReturnObject` value must be `true` or `false` hardcoded at compile time (as you have). You can't use a variable value for whatever is calling it because the whole point of doing this is for the *compiler* to knowswhat the return type will be.

Comment: This was very helpful for defining a default property, thank you.